# Mouse keys is only performing a right click

Tags: mouse

I am new to linux and i finally figured out how to turn on mouse keys and use keypad 5 to emulate a left click but now its only emulating right click and i cannot seem to make it perform a left click. Any ideas?

0

Restarting seems to temporarily fix the issue but eventually it goes back to right click again..

Answer (score 0):

There are chances of it either being the issue of the driver or the mouse.
To check if its a driver issue, shutdown the computer and plug in another mouse and start the computer. If the left click works with the other mouse, it's the issue of the mouse. Otherwise it might be an issue with the driver.
These commands might solve your problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:raof/aubergine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

if that doesn't work, try this command as well:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution did the trick for me: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1407932

Turns out I hit the `-` button (which is a toogle to perform right click) by accident due to proximity in the Num keyboard. Pressing the `*` button goes back to the default setting, no restart necessary.